# Erro ao criar rotas dinamicamente no Django

Tags: python, aplicação-web, django, url-amigável, blog

de boas? Seguinte, to dando meus primeiros passos com o Framework Django e to tendo algumas dificuldades, umas consegui superar "sozinho", essa ta osso. Tenho um projeto básico de blog com algumas views, na que mostra os detalhes do artigo todas as tags são âncoras, mas não ta indo do jeito que deveria, o template ta assim >>

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %} {% block head_title %} {{ Post.Title }} {% endblock %} {% block content %}

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8 right-sidebar">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="post-19 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized tag-boat tag-lake post-container col-md-12">


                <div class="post-article post-details post-details-1  ">

                    <h1 class="title">{{Post.Title}}</h1>
                    <div class="line">

                        <div class="entry-info">

                            <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                                    {{Post.Created_at}}
                                </span>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div style="width: 445px" class="wp-caption alignnone">
                        <img class="wp-image-59" alt="Thumbnail" src="{{Post.Thumbnail.url}}" width="435" height="288">
                    </div>

                    {{Post.Content | safe }}

                    <footer class="line">
                        <span class="entry-info">
                            <i class="fa fa-tags" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <strong>Tags:</strong>
                            {% for tag in Post.Tag.all %}
                            <a href="{% url 'Blog:fortag' slug=tag.slug }" class="mr-1 balde balde-info">{{ tag }}</a> 
                            {% endfor %}
                        </span> 

                    </footer>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


    <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-4 sidebar-area">

        <div class="post-container">

            <div class="post-article">

                <div class="widget-box widget_calendar">
                    <h4 class="title">Calendário</h4>
                    <div id="calendar_wrap" class="calendar_wrap">
                        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
                            var day_of_week = new Array('Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab');
                            var month_of_year = new Array('Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro');

                            var Calendar = new Date();

                            var year = Calendar.getYear(); // Retorna o ano
                            var month = Calendar.getMonth(); // Retorna mes (0-11)
                            var today = Calendar.getDate(); // Retorna dias (1-31)
                            var weekday = Calendar.getDay(); // Retorna dias (1-31)

                            var DAYS_OF_WEEK = 7; // "constant" para o numero de dias na semana
                            var DAYS_OF_MONTH = 31; // "constant" para o numero de dias no mes
                            var cal; // Usado para imprimir na tela

                            Calendar.setDate(1); // Comecar o calendario no dia '1'
                            Calendar.setMonth(month); // Comecar o calendario com o mes atual


                            var TR_start = '<TR>';
                            var TR_end = '</TR>';
                            var highlight_start = '<TD WIDTH="30"><TABLE CELLSPACING=0 BORDER=1 BGCOLOR=DEDEFF BORDERCOLOR=CCCCCC><TR><TD WIDTH=20><B><CENTER>';
                            var highlight_end = '</CENTER></TD></TR></TABLE></B>';
                            var TD_start = '<TD WIDTH="30"><CENTER>';
                            var TD_end = '</CENTER></TD>';

                            cal = '<TABLE BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0 BORDERCOLOR=BBBBBB><TR><TD>';
                            cal += '<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=2>' + TR_start;
                            cal += '<TD COLSPAN="' + DAYS_OF_WEEK + '" BGCOLOR="#F2F2F2"><CENTER><B>';
                            cal += month_of_year[month] + '   ' + year + '</B>' + TD_end + TR_end;
                            cal += TR_start;

                            for (index = 0; index < DAYS_OF_WEEK; index++) {

                                if (weekday == index)
                                    cal += TD_start + '<B>' + day_of_week[index] + '</B>' + TD_end;
                                else
                                    cal += TD_start + day_of_week[index] + TD_end;
                            }

                            cal += TD_end + TR_end;
                            cal += TR_start;

                            for (index = 0; index < Calendar.getDay(); index++)
                                cal += TD_start + '  ' + TD_end;

                            for (index = 0; index < DAYS_OF_MONTH; index++) {
                                if (Calendar.getDate() > index) {
                                    week_day = Calendar.getDay();
                                    if (week_day == 0)
                                        cal += TR_start;
                                    if (week_day != DAYS_OF_WEEK) {
                                        var day = Calendar.getDate();
                                        if (today == Calendar.getDate())
                                            cal += highlight_start + day + highlight_end + TD_end;
                                        else
                                            cal += TD_start + day + TD_end;
                                    }
                                    if (week_day == DAYS_OF_WEEK)
                                        cal += TR_end;
                                }
                                Calendar.setDate(Calendar.getDate() + 1);
                            }
                            cal += '</TD></TR></TABLE></TABLE>';

                            //  MOSTRAR CALENDARIO
                            document.write(cal);
                            //  End -->
                        </SCRIPT>
                        <!-- <nav aria-label="Previous and next months" class="wp-calendar-nav">
                                <span class="wp-calendar-nav-prev"><a href="#">« Oct</a></span>
                                <span class="pad">&nbsp;</span>
                                <span class="wp-calendar-nav-next">&nbsp;</span>
                            </nav> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-box widget_archive">
                    <h4 class="title">Arquivos</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Outubro 2008</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Setembro 2008</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Junho 2008</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="section" id="sidebar-author">
                    <div class="widget Text" data-version="1" id="Text1">
                        <h2 class="title">
                            <span>Sobre o autor</span>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <div class="widget-content">
                                <center>
                                    <div class="photo-profile">
                                        <img alt="Avatar do/da autor(a)" class="image wp-image-139  attachment-medium size-medium" height="300" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" src="{{user.Photo}}">
                                        <br>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    <h2>
                                        <span>
                                                <span>{{Post.Author}}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </h2>
                                    <p>"{{user.Biografy}}"</p>
                                </center>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

As views >>

```
    def fortag(request, slug):

    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug = slug)

    posts = Article.object.filter(Tag = tag)

    context = {
        'tag' : tag,
        'posts' : posts
    }

    return render(request, 'fortag.html', context)


def post(request, pk):

    Post = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)

    return render(request, 'post.html', {'Post': Post})
```

Models >>

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):

    Thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumb/')
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, help_text='Nome do post')
    Created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    Summary = RichTextField(blank=False)
    Content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=False)
    Tag = TaggableManager()
    Author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Title
```

E as urls do app >>

```
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

from .views import home, sobre, post, fortag

app_name = 'Blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name= 'home'),
    path('sobre/', sobre),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', post, name = 'post'),
    path('tag/<slug:slug>/', fortag, name='fortag'),
    path('/ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

O erro que aparece é esse >> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como resolver e pode me ajudar, por favor?

Comment: Tens melhorar alguns detalhes sobre a tua dúvida, tens esse erro quando tentas carregar aquele template, ou quando clicas num botão, mas que não indicas se é o post.html ou o fortag.html, parece-me o fortag.html, mas tens de indicar isso. Repara que o {% url 'Blog:fortag' slug=tag.slug } aparece após o post/2/, essa rota não existe no teu ficheiro urls.py, volto à dúvida inicial, como acontece o erro, ao clicar num botão gerado ou ao renderizar o fortag.html?

Comment: Acontece quando clico em um botão gerado, no caso esse de tag...

Comment: Se fizeres um inspect no browser, vais ver que o que está a gerar nas rotas é localhost:8000/post/[ID]/{% url 'Blog:fortag' slug=tag.slug }, certo?

Comment: Se tiveres o teu projeto versionado, github por exemplo partilha acesso para poder analisar o que se passa, falta partes do teu código para tentar analisar...por exemplo o from taggit.managers import TaggableManager, no teu models.py.

Comment: Ele ta parcialmente completo em https://github.com/Natanapps/blogdjango

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O teu problema está na falta do '%' no fecho da tag, coloca essa linha no lugar da sua.

```
<a href="{% url 'Blog:fortag' slug=tag.slug %}" class="mr-1 balde balde-info"> {{ tag }} </a>
```

Adicionalmente, no teu views.py altera a linha:

```
posts = Article.object.filter(Tag = tag)
```

para

```
posts = Article.objects.filter(Tag = tag)
```

Comment: Valeu, era só isso mesmo. Obrigado!